# Safari Add book mark view

Tags: iphone

safari in iphone has a view that open with a button at the bottom bar.The view contains buttons like Add Bookmark ,Add to home Screen etc.Can I get these controls and btn(square bracket with arrow to right) from UIKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it this is UIAction Sheet.This part is done.Only concern remain is now of the button